Has the text describing the Reviewer Stats changed recently?
Has the text describing the Reviewer Stats changed recently? For example: this suggested edit
Currently, it is: "XXXXX has NN edit suggestions approved, NN edit suggestions rejected, and NN edit suggestions improved."
However, I think it used to be at some time: "XXXXX has approved NN edit suggestions, rejected NN edit suggestions, and improved NN edit suggestions." or something similar.
Or am I mistaken and has it always been what it is currently today?
The text for the Reviewer Stats is currently the same as the text for the Editor Stats.


Dunno if new or not, but looks like a bug, add the tag.

Here's a question with a screenshot of the older version of the text.

And yes, there was a recent change in this, which most likely introduced this new bug. Won't be the first time or last time fixing or changing something cause new bug.
